# Web Api DateTime not binding from JSON

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

This is my **Model**

```
public class PersonVModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my **JSON**

```
{
    "FirstName": "Artur",
    "BrithDate": "4/22/1991"
}
```

The strings, bools, and integers bind's well, but **DateTime** don't
[image]

I have tried with **[DataType(DataType.Date)]** attribute too, it doesn't work too.

*Any solutions?*

Comment: Is the spelling mistake in the json a simple question rewrite error or actually there?

Comment: It is also likely you'll have to implement a custom model binder and tell it how to parse that very localized date format.

Comment: That's not a valid Json date.

Comment: `4/22/1991` is not a valid json date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo : "B**ri**thDate" vs "B**ir**thDate"

By default MVC model binder just sets properties to default values when binding fails.
You can check model validity with [IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.isvalid(v=vs.118).aspx) property.

We created special filter which throws exception with the information where binding failed. It helps a lot with AngularJS and mistypings.

```
public class RequireValidModel : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework before the action method executes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ModelStateDictionary state = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;

        if (!state.IsValid)
        {
            var perPropertyMessages = state.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                                           .Select(kvp =>
                                               new
                                               {
                                                   Property = kvp.Key,
                                                   Value = kvp.Value.Value != null ? kvp.Value.Value.AttemptedValue: null,
                                                   ErrorMessages = kvp.Value.Errors.Select(err => err.Exception != null ? err.Exception.Message : err.ErrorMessage)
                                               })
                                           .Select(propertyErrors =>
                                               new
                                               {
                                                   propertyErrors.Property,
                                                   propertyErrors.Value,
                                                   ErrorMessages = string.Join("\n", propertyErrors.ErrorMessages)
                                               })
                                           .Select(
                                               propertyErrors =>
                                                   string.Format("(property: {0}, attempted value: {1}, errors: {2}\n)", propertyErrors.Property,
                                                       propertyErrors.Value, propertyErrors.ErrorMessages));

            var finalMessage = string.Format("Invalid model state:\n{0}", string.Join(",\n", perPropertyMessages));

            throw new InvalidOperationException(finalMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, to avoid problems with dates, convert all date strings to Date objects at the very place where data is received.

Answer (score 3):

Your Json contains a US-specific date string, which is why it isn't recognized as a valid date. This string would also cause issues with any C# code that *didn't* run with a US locale.

While JSON itself doesn't specify a date type, everyone nowadays uses Javascript's ISO8601 format, eg: `"2012-04-21T18:25:43-05:00Z"`

Comment: Not necessarily only javascript's iso format - it's a fairly language agnostic standard. =)

Comment: Didn't say it is. But people did end up adopting Javascript's format instead of the initial attempts to use a unix timestamp-like format

Comment: Oh! I managed to parse the grammar now. Silly Anglosisms. My mistake.

Comment: No, just speed typing while also trying to work. I had to read the sentence myself twice